# How does one go about reading the options from a fullcalendar object

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm creating multiple fullcalendar's on a single page and i would like to write a single event render callback such that it can read the options from the fullcalendar instance that it is called from/in, things like minTime and maxTime, not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is this the Fullcalendar you're using? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 9):

you can do something like this:

```
var minTime = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'minTime');
```

the `option` method isn't really documented, but it should work